# C++ exponential_distribution occasionally returns inf where 0 is expected

Tags: c++, random

In a project, I am generating millions of expo(lambda) random variables, where lambda is potentially very large. When using `std::exponential_distribution<float>` I occasionally get a return value of `inf`. I would understand this if lambda were close to 0, but when lambda is large a value very close to zero is expected. For example, the following program usually terminates after several million draws:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

int main(void)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());

    float lambda = 1000000.0;
    float val = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
    {
        std::exponential_distribution<float> dist(lambda);
        val = dist(generator);

        if(isinf(val))
        {
            std::cout << i << " " << val << " failure" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If there is some error (due to precision) in the function, why does it return `inf` instead of the more convenient `0.0`? Is there any way to fix this, besides for manually checking that the output is finite? Thanks.

Comment: Does the same happen with `double` instead of `float`? An 8-bit exponent seems tiny for a large lambda. Honestly I'm not sure than an 11-bit exponent gives you that much headroom

Comment: _"...Some implementations may occasionally return infinity if RealType is float. This is LWG issue 2524..."_ source (has a link to the issue):  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/exponential_distribution

Comment: Using ```double``` fixes the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard Critten's comment says:

> "...Some implementations may occasionally return infinity if RealType is float. This is LWG issue 2524..." source (has a link to the issue): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/exponential_distribution

Switching to `double` doesn't fix this problem, but rather, it merely reduces the chance of seeing it (or at least makes it negligible). As the LWG issue points out, the underlying issue is that `generate_canonical` (which some implementations could make use of) might return 1.0 in rare cases, so that `-log(1-generate_canonical())` could output infinity. In practice, this was more likely with `float` than with `double` since there are considerably fewer numbers that `generate_canonical` could produce with `float` than with `double` (in practice, 2^24 as opposed to 2^53). (In any case, there are other problems with naive implementations of right-tailed distributions, such as the exponential distribution; see "[Reconditioning your quantile function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07949)".)